# Show a sum of independent random variable weighted by variance converging to $0$ almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Consider $(X_{k})$ a sequence of mutually independent random variables such that $$\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=2^{k^{2}})=\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=-2^{k^{2}})=\dfrac{1}{2}\ \text{for}\ k\ \text{odd,}$$ and $$\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=2^{k^{2}})=\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=-2^{k^{2}})=\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=4^{k^{2}})=\mathbb{P}(X_{k}=-4^{k^{2}})=\dfrac{1}{4}\ \text{for}\ k\ \text{even.}$$

Denote $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$, and let $\sigma_{n}^{2}=\operatorname{Var}(S_{n})$. I'd like to show that $$\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}X_{k}}{\sigma_{n}}\longrightarrow 0\ \text{a.s.}$$

Here is some computation result, $\mathbb{E}X_{k}=0$ for all $k$, $$\operatorname{Var}(X_{k})=2^{2k^{2}}\ \text{for}\ k\ \text{odd,}$$ and $$\operatorname{Var}(X_{k})=\dfrac{2^{2k^{2}}}{2}(1+2^{2k^{2}}) \ \text{for}\ k\ \text{even.}$$

It is really painful to compute $\sigma_{n}$, even though I can compute it, it is hard to compute $\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$, what can I do?

In fact through this work I was about to show $(X_{k})$ not converging to any distribution, so my thought was to make $S_{n}$ concentrated on $X_{n}$ so that we can just compute $X_{n}/\sigma_{n}$. Then if I modify the sequence so that the odd and even terms converges to different distribution, then the limit will not exist.

This is why I need $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}X_{k}/\sigma_{n}\longrightarrow 0$ a.s.

However this turned out that I need to compute $\sigma_{2n}$ and $\sigma_{2n-1}$ to get the difference between odd and even term.

**Thus, if one can come up another simpler $(X_{k})$ such that it does not converge to anything in distribution, we can forget my question and the expected complicated computation.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you do not need an exact formula for $\sigma_n$, but only an equivalent. let $s_i$ be the variance of $X_i$. Then 
$$
\sigma_{2n-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}s_{2i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_{2i-1}
$$
and using the expression for $s_{2i}$ and $s_{2i-1}$ that you got, and showing that only the last term in the sum matter, we derive that 
$$
\sigma_{2n-1}\sim 2^{16(n-1)^2}.
$$
By a similar method, we also derive that $\sigma_{2n}\sim 2^{16n^2}$
hence the series $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[S_{n-1}^2/\sigma_n\right]$ converges.

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you so much.